# How can I added a text for one file to another files "Multi Text files"

Tags: shell, unix

I'll be grateful If someone help me with below issue; I have one file `hello.txt` which contains the text "Hello all " and I want this text to be added with multiple files has text "this me", and first text to be above with each files.

What I mean is, hello.txt has the text = "Hello all ", and multiple files 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt . . 20.txt all have the text "this me".

What I need is 1.txt ..... 20.txt the text be "hello all this me"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want 100%, but something like this ought to do the job:

```
set -e
for f in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt ...
do
    cat hello.txt "$f" > "$f"T
    mv -f "$f"T "$f"
done
```